# Github made canser in my game

Tags: github, game-maker

I am working on a project for shcool and in order to work with my partner effectivly we are using git hub. we are making the game in game maker, but there is a problem where a room called room0.room.gmx is giving me an error. I deleted it in the game maker file, and have deleted it in finder. It still is giving me issues so I right clicked on it in git hub to see if there was some version of it still existing.... it said the file dosent exist.... but it is contained somewhere in my computer. I cant find this anywhere on the internet! Please help!!!

Comment: What kind of help do you think we can provide?

Comment: If you did any commits you can checkout the file from the last commit. git checkout -- name-of-file-YOU-deleted

Comment: so game maker says the filie is in the repository file, rooms\room0.room.gmx. I have found and deleted the file, found and deleted the folder, and then gave up and deleted the project, and am going to uncommit the change if i could just commit it to master and sync. but even though there is no conseveible way it exists, and it even says it doesnt exist, it still wont let commit or discard changes

Comment: is there a way to discard all changes and overide any errors? it just saying that the room may exist in another application, even though there isnt... i checked

Comment: acctually screw it, im just gonna make a new respository and have my freind put the old file in it and just go from there. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

I can't cure canser, but deleting the tumorous room won't be enought. You need to also delete it in the GameMaker studio project. The problem is that somewhere in your project file is a link to all the files you use. If you delete the room file, GameMaker has no clue and still thinks it exists somewhere, and still points to it.

Maybe it isn't exactly your problem, but a more detailed question would help.